# How to get Googleapis response in english only?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, google-maps, google-api

I'm using the **googleapis** service to get user's locations, current city name + country name:

```
NSString *urlString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/xml?latlng=%f,%f&sensor=false",latitude,longitude];

urlString = [urlString stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:urlString];

NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];

// Send the request
NSData *data = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:nil error:nil];
```

I get an XML file with data, and than using NSXMLParser to get the necessary info.
From some reason **sometimes** the info is in **english** and sometimes **not**, and I need it **ONLY** in en.

I tried to override the language of the app with this code:

```
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject: [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"en", nil] forKey:@"AppleLanguages"];
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];
```

But nothing happens, what should I do?

Comment: Have you tried to add `&language=en` to your request URL?

Comment: Great, Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

In the [Google Maps API Documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/#geocoding), it says :

> **Optional parameters in a geocoding request:**
>
> language — The language in which to return results. See the [list of supported domain languages](https://developers.google.com/maps/faq#languagesupport). Note that we often update supported languages so this list may not be exhaustive. If language is not supplied, the geocoder will attempt to use the native language of the domain from which the request is sent wherever possible.

So, you just have to specify the language as a parameter in your request.
For english : `language=en`

Comment: Where should i put it in the address?

Comment: Yes. `NSString *urlString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/xml?latlng=%f,%f&sensor=false&language=en",latitude,longitude];`

Comment: for some reason, it does not work, I still receive the locality in arabic
https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?language=en&latlng=15.5315577839033,32.576438337564&sensor=true&key=AIzaSyAOERDghFMnddy1nnv_pQfYDYNQh9axXdw

Comment: According to the documentation: "the country name is returned in the language you requested, but the rest of the address will be specific to the location you are geocoding"